# New Vote to Closed Option - Abandoned

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, abandonment

I'd like to see another option for Vote to Close: Abandoned

Frequently, when trying to answer unanswered questions I'll run across questions that the asker has seemingly abandoned:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343853
[Bugs in OrderByOn property in Microsoft Access 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071458)

Other members have asked questions trying to get enough information from the asker to help. And yet they've not responded, even months later. Why am I wasting my time looking at a question the asker doesn't care about.

I think its safe to close a question that's two+ months old without enough information in it to answer it (as evident by the lack of answers), and without an asker who's still interested in getting the question answered (as evident by the lack of responses and updates to comments left by other users).

There's very little value to the internet in a question that can't be answered. In some ways it is of negative value, because it's going to draw people in who are having a similar problem, but they will be wasting their time because they won't find an answer.

Comment: There's an automated system in place to delete these posts automatically, though last I checked it left them around for a year first.

Comment: What's wrong with "too localized" then? Then delete it.

Comment: Not to abandon this question :-)  Yah, I can see "too localized" making sense.

Comment: If the question can't be answered for lack of detail, and the asker hasn't responded to requests for clarification, in my view that falls squarely under "Not a Real Question: this question cannot reasonably be answered in its current form." I agree with the sentiment expressed in your question, though, so +1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not like this.

If other people have the same (or similar) problem, then there's value in the question even if the original poster is no longer interested (or changed careers, or died, or...). If the question has no value in itself, it should (after a month) have been closed for being too localized (or not a real question).

I think that if the automatic system to delete "dead" questions after a year is in place as Adam described, then that is sufficient.

Comment: I think that the important point here is not that the asker doesn't care about the answer, but that the question doesn't really provide enough information to be answered in a way that would be useful to anyone, and requests for such information have been made without reply.

Comment: @Josh - This case, I think, falls under "not a real question". ("That can't be answered; can you provide more info?" ["No" | <silence>] "Well, then, that's not a real question.")

Comment: Fully agree; that was in fact my response (in a comment) to this question. :)

Comment: Except that not all abandoned questions are vague. Some are clear and the answer is definitive, so allowing mods to accept the correct/highest-voted answer would allow the question to be "closed" in a better way than just closing or deleting it.